# Array Manipulation HackerRank in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I try to resolve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem) exercise in Hacker Rank:

> Starting with a 1-indexed array of zeros and a list of operations, for
> each operation add a value to each the array element between two given
> indices, inclusive. Once all operations have been performed, return
> the maximum value in the array.

**Example:**

```
n = 10
queries = [[1,5,3],[4,8,7],[6,9,1]]
```

Queries are interpreted as follows:

```
a b k
1 5 3
4 8 7
6 9 1
```

Add the values of `k` between the indices `a` and `b` inclusive:

```
index->  1 2 3  4  5 6 7 8 9 10
        [0,0,0, 0, 0,0,0,0,0, 0]
        [3,3,3, 3, 3,0,0,0,0, 0]
        [3,3,3,10,10,7,7,7,0, 0]
        [3,3,3,10,10,8,8,8,1, 0]
```

The largest value is  after all operations are performed.
Function Description

Complete the function arrayManipulation in the editor below.

arrayManipulation has the following parameters:

int n - the number of elements in the array
int queries[q][3] - a two dimensional array of queries where each queries[i] contains three integers, a, b, and k.
Returns

int - the maximum value in the resultant array
Input Format

The first line contains two space-separated integers  and , the size of the array and the number of operations.
Each of the next  lines contains three space-separated integers ,  and , the left index, right index and summand.
I used this code:

```
function arrayManipulation($n, $queries) {
    for($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++){
        $a[$i] = 0;
    }
    foreach($queries as $index => $query){   
            $e = $query[0];
            $p = $query[1];
            $value = $query[2];
            for($b = $e; $b <= $p; $b++){
                $a[$b] += $value;
            }
    }
    return max($a);
}
```

All work except for biggest test case (Runtime Error), how i can improve that?
Seems like very easy task but i can't solve it.

The logic i have used:

- Create an `array` with index = `$n` (size of array)
- Start to `foreach` `$queries` and create a tmp variable with:

  - `$e` min of range
  - `$p` max of range
  - `$value` the value need for the sum
- Use `for-loop` for sum value into array `$a` base to index from min and max
- return `max` of `$a`

Comment: Your second link ends up with a 401 (unauthorized) error. Can you include the relevant information in the question itself instead of linking to an external resource?

Comment: Was a biggest test case like 20000 row, i can't add here because will exceed the max size of post.

Comment: Please share more details. What is "this problem"? What kind of input breaks the algorithm? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: **Runtime Error** is the problem

Comment: As your code does not print anything related to "Runtime Error", you need to share more details

Comment: Hacker rank "test" have a maximum time, seems like my script go runtime. which details you need more ? The only way is use test case, but i can't post it here

Comment: In general, problems like this require you to find a clever solution that's not O(n^2), so that you don't exceed the time limit on large inputs. In this case, what you need to do is turn the list of operations into an array containing the total amount to add to each array element.

Comment: Isn't that already the case? `$queries` contains the range and value to add. how could I enclose it any other way?

Comment: @ShivamSharma i really don't understand. You can be more specific

Comment: [Already a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56327605/8494462) is posted using Prefix sum.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array Manipulation : HackerRank Questions : JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56249944/array-manipulation-hackerrank-questions-java)

Comment: `JAVA != PHP` :)

Comment: Logic remains same everywhere... Such questions are for improving DS algo, logical ability and problem solving skills. :)

Comment: Logic but the situation in not the same :D I don't know java(who used ? ) I prefer php and js ecc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way to solve this problem in O(m * log(m)). It passes all test cases.

Look at my solution:

```php
function arrayManipulation($n, $queries)
{
    $arr = [];

    foreach ($queries as $query) {
        $start = $query[0] - 1;
        $end = $query[1];
        $value = $query[2];

        $arr[$start] = ($arr[$start] ?? 0) + $value;

        if ($end < $n) {
            $arr[$end] = ($arr[$end] ?? 0) - $value;
        }
    }

    ksort($arr);

    $answer = 0;
    $currentSum = 0;

    foreach ($arr as $change) {
        $currentSum += $change;
        $answer = max($answer, $currentSum);
    }

    return $answer;
}
```

- At first we should avoid using array of size `n`.
- Then we construct array of value changes `$arr`, not of real values (like you've done).
- And finally we just run through the resulting array and emulate real value for every iteration. And remember max value, of course. This will be our answer.